# Select from mysql table unique records according to a Field

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL which I store registrations info.

I need to select all rows but only the latest according to email field and ID field

**My table:**

[image: table1]

***and I need***

[image: result table]

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why

Comment: If any of the answers below have solved/helped you to solve your problem, then kindly accept it as answer/upvote the answer. That'll be really helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from yourTablename
where (id,email) in 
        (select max(id),email from yourTablename group by email);
```

**Another approach with Inner Join:**(As suggested by Tim)

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT email, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM t t2
    GROUP BY email
) t2
    ON t1.email = t2.email AND
       t1.id  = t2.max_id;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55b7e4/6/2)

Comment: Use an inner join, rather than a subquery, for optimal results.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, this is what I attempted to write earlier, ultimately messing it up.  Plus one for your answer.  Actually, it still isn't clear if they want max id or max name.

Comment: Thank you. Question says he want max id, hence i used id. But in his answer he used max name

Comment: The name coincidentally works for the exact sample data, because `name2` happens to be greater than `name1`, but in practice that might not work out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

Using

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT email, MAX(name) AS max_name
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY email
) t2
    ON t1.email = t2.email AND
       t1.name  = t2.max_name;
```

Worked fine.

Thanks

Comment: I guess it'll only worked if name are in increment order too.Interchange name1 & name2 and you'll get different result. Unless you want row with max(name)and not max(id), this won't work.